# comboBox item filled from 2 columns INSERT INTO SqlCommand only one column - SelectedItem

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, combobox, selecteditem

I have this code below which fills combobox with 2 values in one item(row in combobox) now I would like to insert only for example the val1(numeric 9,2) item into DB without tval1 (char). How would SqlCommand INSERT INTO look like if I would like to INSERT INTO DB only val1, val2 or val3 depending on selected value? I know how to insert simple filled combobox, but how can I set what I would like to insert into DB?

```
var cb4 = new SqlCommand("SELECT cena1,cena2,cena3,tcena1,tcena2,tcena3 FROM zajezd WHERE akce=" + zakce.Text, spojeni);
 SqlDataReader dr4 = cb4.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr4.Read())
        {
            string val1 = Convert.ToString(dr4["cena1"]);
            string val2 = Convert.ToString(dr4["cena2"]);
            string val3 = Convert.ToString(dr4["cena3"]);
            string tval1 = Convert.ToString(dr4["tcena1"]);
            string tval2 = Convert.ToString(dr4["tcena2"]);
            string tval3 = Convert.ToString(dr4["tcena3"]);

            comboBox4.Items.Add(val1 + " " + tval1);

            comboBox4.Items.Add(val2 + " " + tval2);
            comboBox4.Items.Add(val3 + " " + tval3);

        }
        dr4.Close();
        dr4.Dispose();

        spojeni.Close();
```

Thank you for your time reading this. I have no clue how to do this.

This is my code for inserting comboBox with single value -

```
  prikaz.Parameters.AddWithValue("@variable", comboBox1.Text);
```

How should I improve it to save only val1? thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First,
You must create your own class .

```
public class ComboboxItem
{
    public string val { get; set; }
    public string tval { get; set; }

    public  string DisplayText {get  { return val + " " + tval;}  }
}
```

Then, change your code:

```
var cb4 = new SqlCommand("SELECT cena1,cena2,cena3,tcena1,tcena2,tcena3 FROM zajezd WHERE akce=" + zakce.Text, spojeni);
SqlDataReader dr4 = cb4.ExecuteReader();
while (dr4.Read())
    {
        string val1 = Convert.ToString(dr4["cena1"]);
        string val2 = Convert.ToString(dr4["cena2"]);
        string val3 = Convert.ToString(dr4["cena3"]);
        string tval1 = Convert.ToString(dr4["tcena1"]);
        string tval2 = Convert.ToString(dr4["tcena2"]);
        string tval3 = Convert.ToString(dr4["tcena3"]);

        ComboboxItem cbxItem1 = new ComboboxItem();
        cbxItem1.val = val1;
        cbxItem1.tval = tval1;
        comboBox4.Items.Add(cbxItem1);

        ComboboxItem cbxItem2 = new ComboboxItem();
        cbxItem2.val = val2;
        cbxItem2.tval = tval2;
        comboBox4.Items.Add(cbxItem2);

        ComboboxItem cbxItem3 = new ComboboxItem();
        cbxItem3.val = val3;
        cbxItem3.tval = tval3;
        comboBox4.Items.Add(cbxItem3);

        //Set display member and value member
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "DisplayText";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "val";
    }
    dr4.Close();
    dr4.Dispose();

    spojeni.Close();
```

and finally, to insert, you must use the selectedValue of the combobox:

```
prikaz.Parameters.AddWithValue("@variable", comboBox1.SelectedValue);
```